# Is it possible to change the colour of specific comments in Eclispe

Tags: colors, comments

I know it's possible to change the colour of all  single and multi lines comments in eclispe in a piece of code or program but I was wondering if it possible to change the colour of an one or multiple but not all single and multi line comments in eclispe and if so how ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Navigate to *Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring > Comments*. [Here's an image of the window in Eclipse to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Fvy.jpg)